# Android - Button icon loads after function call instead of before

Tags: android

I have this code:

```
fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if(!clicked){
            clicked = true;
            fab.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_media_stop);
            char[] userInput = et.getText().toString().toLowerCase().toCharArray();
            compareToMap(userInput);
        }else{
            clicked = false;
            fab.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_media_play);
        }
    }
});
```

When the floating action button is clicked, I want it to change to a stop symbol and then execute the function afterwards. What is happening is that the code is being executed before the image on the button changes. The image only changes once all of the code has been executed from the `compareToMap` function even though it is placed before it in the code. Is there a way to make sure that the image changes before the `compareToMap` function executes?

Note: The `compareToMap` function contains `Thread.sleep` methods which is causing the UI to block (I think), but shouldn't the image change before that function is executed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this moment the UI didn't load yet. If you want to do some work after the UI is loaded you can use the class Handler.

```
long postDelay = 100; //The delay (in milliseconds) until the Runnable will be executed
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //Code that you want to execute after the UI is loaded
        compareToMap(userInput);
    }   
}, postDelay);
```

Note: You can't use Thread.sleep on the UI main thread. You can learn more here. https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html.

Answer (score 0):

You can use AsyncTask to execute the compareToMap(userInput) method, this will run the compareToMap method in a separated thread and the UI will not be blocked; something like this :

```
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        fab.setImageResource(!clicked ? R.drawable.ic_media_stop : R.drawable.ic_media_play);
        if (!clicked) {
            // Cancel the executing AsyncTask if there's one already running
            if (mAsyncTask != null) {
                mAsyncTask.cancel(true);
            }
            mAsyncTask = new AsyncTask<String, Void, Void>() {
                        @Override
                        protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
                            compareToMap(userInput);
                            return null;
                        }
                    };
            mAsyncTask.execute();
        }
        clicked != clicked;
    }
});
```

More info about AsyncTasks [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) or you can check this [tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/04/android-downloading-file-by-showing-progress-bar/).